# Unable to import a file from different directory even with __init__.py

Tags: python

I have created a utility folder where I am planning to store my general functions but I am not able to import that package into different folders.

My Folder structure is:

```
utils
├── __init_.py
└── readData.py
```

```py
import json

class ProcessJsonFile():
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.fileName = fileName
    
    def readFileData(self):
        file = open(self.fileName)
        data = json.load(file)
        print(data)
```

In my other folder, I am trying to call the readData.py function like this

```
from utils import readData

def execute():
   readData.ProcessJsonFile("test.json")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute()
```

but it's not working and this is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readData.py", line 3, in <module>
    from utils import readData
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

Comment: Is `__init_.py` a typo in the question?

Comment: What "other folder" are we talking about, and what (if anything) did you do to let Python know where `util/` is so that it can try to interpret it as a package?

Comment: `from utils import ...` is an absolute import, meaning there needs to be a package named `utils` in a directory whose name appears in the module search path `sys.path`.

Comment: Yea.
Another folder is where I am trying to refer to the readData. No, I have not. How can I do that? @chepner

Comment: I would install your code to a virtual environment.

Comment: Check [this guide](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) to relative/absolute imports, it seems to be easy to solve having all information on the problem (which is not the case in the question).
As others mentioned, to get more help we'd need to know from where you want to import `utils` and how is your environment.

Answer (score 0):

The file name should be **`__init__.py`** under the utils module.
also, make sure that you have set the correct working directory if you are running from some IDE.
On a side note Please follow python naming conventions for the module, class, and filename.
for example, the filename should not be readData.py it should be read_data.py

Comment: \PEP-8 discourages the use of `_` in a module name (aside from using a leading underscore to signify an extension module used by a Python module of the "same" name). The conventional name would be `readdata.py`, not `read_data.py`.

Comment: Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability.

Comment: It's arguable that it does here. In any case, modules names also tend not to be verb phrases like `read data`, but rather noun phrases like `data reader`.

Comment: I agree @chepner